# How do I prevent 100% width images from expanding to the body size when inside a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a layout: one container with four columns. It formats correctly as long as I explicitly size the images inside each column. I'd like to specify percentages for the image width so the layout will be flexible, but when I do the images expand to the width of the main container, not the columns that contain the images.

The relevant (I think) bit is near the bottom.

CSS Desk: http://www.cssdesk.com/Gb2Qd

HTML

```
<div id=maincontent>

<div id="shop-panels" class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="panel" id="panel1">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/dn7cdoifp/sedan.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            Shop Sedans
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel " id="panel2">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://s1.postimg.org/ujt0z038v/truck.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            Shop Trucks
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel " id="panel3">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/w16ku1ymt/minivan.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            Shop Minivans
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel " id="panel4">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://s22.postimg.org/6gw49w8gh/suv.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            Shop SUVs
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;

}

div#maincontent {
    width: 980px;
    background: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#shop-panels {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    }
#shop-panels div.panel {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: .5em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #A00;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(200,0,0,1),rgba(127,0,0,1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(200,0,0,1),rgba(127,0,0,1));
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(200,0,0,1),rgba(127,0,0,1));
    }
#shop-panels div.panel:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    }
#shop-panels div.panel:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    }
#shop-panels div.panel:hover {
    background: #C00;
    }
#shop-panels div.panel .content {
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 1em;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    }
#shop-panels div.panel .content img {
    position: relative;
    /* THIS IS THE CULPRIT RIGHT HERE */
    width: 100%;
    /* IF THIS VALUE IS 190px, EVERYTHING'S FINE. */
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
#shop-panels div.panel > .caption {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: .7em 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#shop-panels div.panel {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}
#shop-panels div.panel .content img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://www.cssdesk.com/tjsDx

---

Why this works:

```
flex: 1 0 auto;
```

...in your code, means:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: auto;
```

...which is clearly ***not*** what you want. If you don't want your flex-items to grow past 25%, you need to set it to:

```
flex: 0 1 25%;
```

or, alternatively, set the flex items `max-width` to:

```
max-width: calc(25% - 1em); /* subtracting margins */
```

Sidenote: don't work on prefixed CSS. Use only the clean syntax and use [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) at the end. For maximum compatibility, set `> 0%` in box below it.

Comment: I learned something new today, thank you. As to the CSS, I use CSSCrush which does all the prefixing - what I posted was post-crush.

Comment: @BillinKansasCity: As a side-note, @willanderson's answer works too. `flex:1` translates to `flex:1 1 0%`. It sets `grow` to 1 and leaves `shrink` and `basis` at default values. It's good when you don't know the number of items and you want them to just fit the space. Mine is better when you want wrapping, allowing for control over the width of each item, displayed in multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

change the flex values of `#shop-panels div.panel` from `1 0 auto` to just `1`, like this:

```
#shop-panels div.panel {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    ...
}
```

By setting [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex?v=example#Formal_syntax) (the second value) to `0`, you are not allowing them to shrink